# REST API video.upload as Fan Page, Invalid Token

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

I can't seem to get the syntax correct for uploading videos as a Fan Page, video uploading works fine when I do it as a user, but not when specifying an access token for the Fan Page (Code sample below):

```
        var mediaObject = new FacebookMediaObject
        {
            FileName = fileName,
            ContentType = "video/" + videoType
        };

        mediaObject.SetValue(videoData);

        dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject();
        parameters.source = mediaObject;
        parameters.title = Title;
        parameters.description = Description;
        parameters.method = "video.upload";

        // Get the access token of the posting user if we need to
        if (userID != this.FacebookAccount.UserAccountId)
        {
            parameters.access_token = this.getPostingUserAuthToken(userID);
        }
        else
        {
            parameters.access_token = this.FacebookAccount.SessionKey;
        }

        dynamic publishResponse = this.FacebookConnection.Post(parameters);
```

I have no such problems with Photos/Status messages as a fan page and the user has manage_pages permissions.

Can anyone point me in the right direction here please, all I'm getting back is 'invalid OAuth 2.0 token'.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to do this for some time, althought i didn't succeded. I believe that it is bugged or it is not possible to upload a video to fan page because of this bug: http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=6283